# Error: LocationData Flutter

Tags: flutter

Tengo un peque;o error en un proyecto, en la variable currentLocation, creo que es un error de tipo de dato, pero en la declaracion de la clase dice que es correcto, alguna sugerencia porfavor[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 Future<LatLng> getUserLocation() async {
var currentLocation = <String, double>{};

final location = LocationManager.Location();
try {
  **currentLocation = await location.getLocation();**
  final lat = currentLocation["latitude"];
  final lng = currentLocation["longitude"];

  //final dist =
  final center = LatLng(lat, lng);
  return center;
} on Exception {
  currentLocation = null;
  return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

El tipo de dato de retorno de `getLocation()` es `LocationData`, debes cambiar la declaración de la variable.

Cambia esto:

```
var currentLocation = <String, double>{};
```

Por esto:

```
LocationData currentLocation;
```